# Calculate column values in pandas based on previous rows of data in another column

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns, calculation

Let's say I have a table with two columns: Date and Amount. Number of rows are not more than 3000.

Row Date Amount

1 15/05/2021 248

2 16/05/2021 115

3 17/05/2021 387

4 18/05/2021 214

5 19/05/2021 678

6 20/05/2021 489

7 21/05/2021 875

8 22/05/2021 123

................

I need to add a third column which will calculate the trim mean values based on the Amount column.

I will be using this function: my_table['TrimMean'] = stats.trim_mean(my_table['Amount'], 0.1), but adapted for my problem.

The problem is that this is not a fixed range, but a dynamic one, following this logic: for each row in my table, the trim mean value will be calculated based on the previous 90 values of the Amount column, starting from the row above current row. If there are less that 90 values, then calculate with whatever amount of rows is available.

e.g. TrimMean[1000]=stats.trim_mean(array from column Amount containing values from rows 910 to 999) TrimMean[12]=stats.trim_mean(array from column Amount containing values from rows 1 to 11)

Hope that makes sense.

Is there any way I can calculate this in a simple way, without going through row by row iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate the `trim_mean` by applying the function over a `rolling` window of size `90` and `min_periods=1`

```
from scipy.stats import trim_mean

df['Amount'].rolling(90, min_periods=1).apply(trim_mean, args=(0.1, )).shift()
```

---

```
0           NaN
1    248.000000
2    181.500000
3    250.000000
4    241.000000
5    328.400000
6    355.166667
7    429.428571
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Before trying to implement this with Python, I was using  Excel. Not sure if you can try, but do you get the same values Excel vs python calculation? For the data I'm using the results seem to be different (not by much, there is a small margin)

Comment: @George Unfortunately I can not check with excel. Can you quantify the small margin?

Comment: I am trying now to see if I can find some information if the Excel formula is same as the python. Debugging would help, but I can't apply it on encapsulated formulas like this, or maybe I don't know how... I will let you know the result. Thank you for your help, your answer is very helpful.

Comment: Ok, so Excel parameter includes both upper and lower percentage range, so the equivalent of 0.1 from python is 0.2 in Excel. Your solution works great. Many thanks!